# Why are my "replacement parameters" getting transformed into empty strings?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, model

This is the code when "at rest":

```
var report_parms = {
    GUID: "@Model.GUID",
    SerialNumber: "@Model.SerialNumber",
    ReportName: "@Model.ReportName"
};
```

This is what it looks like at run-time, when stepping through the jQuery:

```
var report_parms = {
    GUID: "",
    SerialNumber: "",
    ReportName: ""
};
```

...and this is the exception I get because those strings are empty:

**System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  StackTrace:
       at TLDReporter_SL.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)**

...in this C# method:

```
   private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptObject Parms = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("get_report_parms");
        string ReportName = Parms.GetProperty("ReportName").ToString(); <--- This is the line that blows up
        switch (ReportName)
        {
            default:
                this.RootVisual = new ReceiptRpt();
                break;
        }
    }
```

So my question is (this is legacy code I'm trying to grok): What is that "@Model.Bla" stuff supposed to do? Is anybody familiar with this sort of "magic"? It seems odd to me that:

0) The word "model" is capitalized ("Model"), whereas the model referenced in Razor syntax above is not:

```
@model TLDReporter.Models.TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel
```

And!:

1) Those "replacement parameters" are encased in quotes.

Is this something totally "home[grown,spun]" that I'll have to unravel myself, or is this sort of thing something of a known quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is that "@Model.Bla" stuff supposed to do?

That Razor syntax means simply, render the property "Bla" of the page model.  This line:

```
@model TLDReporter.Models.TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel
```

indicates the type of the page model.  You'll have to find the controller code to figure out exactly how the instance of that class is being returned (or not).  You should be able to find a class like "XyzController" with a method returning "ActionResult" or similar, that has something like this:

```
var model = new TLDReporter.Models.TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel();
return View(model);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; I've been mucking about in the model/controller code, which had oodles of stuff that was put there and then abandoned (dead code), so maybe I inadvertently buried some code alive that was still breathing.

Comment: Even in the oldest version of TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel that I have, there are no declarations of GUID, SerialNumber, or ReportName; they are only in the Controller...

Comment: @ClayShannon now that is strange, because the view clearly seems to be assuming they are properties of the model ... what is their role in the Controller, then?

Comment: my bad, I found them skulking about like cockroaches in an ancestor class.

Comment: @ClayShannon lol ... your sheer contempt for the codebase is ... vivid.